# django migrate not updating on sql database tables therefor raising django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'field list'")

Tags: python, django

I'm having issues with my django project in development. It was working fine till I updated the model fields then it went haywire. Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

equipment_choices = (
    (1, "Contact Grill & Panini Grill"),
    (2, "Char Grill"),
    (3, "Griddle"),
    (4, "Salamender Grill"),
    (5, "Toaster Grill"),
    (6, "Boiling Top"),
    (7, "Gas Hob"),
    (8, "Freestanding Fryer"),
    (9, "Counter Top Fryer"),
    (10, "Filtration Fyrer"),
    (11, "Chip Scuttle"),)

class Recipe(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    prep_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(500),
        ]
    )
    cook_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(500),
        ]
    )
    additional_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0),
            MaxValueValidator(200),
        ]
    )
    total_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(500),
        ]
    )
    ingridients = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    method =  models.TextField(unique=True)
    equipment = MultiSelectField(choices=equipment_choices, max_choices=5, max_length=11)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(500),
        ]
    )
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=(
        (1, "★☆☆☆☆"),
        (2, "★★☆☆☆"),
        (3, "★★★☆☆"),
        (4, "★★★★☆"),
        (5, "★★★★★"),
    )
    )
```

here is the MovieList view:

```
def movie_list(request):
    return render(request, 'movie_list.html', {
        'recipes': Recipe.objects.all(),
    })
```

When I press a button that works with the model I get the following error

```
Internal Server Error: /recipes/list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'recipes_recipe.title' in 'field list'")
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/buddy/takein/mysite/recipes/views.py", line 15, in movie_list
    return render(request, 'movie_list.html', {
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 194, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1866, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/buddy/.virtualenvs/takein/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'recipes_recipe.title' in 'field list'")
```

I've tried migrate,
migrate --fake (after dropping app table)
then truncating migrations database table still no difference.

At some point when migrating it didn't create a new table I had to manually add it in the db with just the id column. Nothing happened beyond there

Comment: It seems it's crashing in the view `movie_list`. Can you post the code for this?

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans def movie_list(request):
    return render(request, 'movie_list.html', {
        'recipes': Recipe.objects.all(),
    })

Comment: Thanks, can you also post the template `movie_list.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `migrations` and `SQLite3` files, then rerun the migration commands.